# Pseudo-element background image doesn't appear

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-shapes

I have a `div` element with a triangle-border and I'm trying to place an image above it using an `::after` pseudo-element with `background-image`. The method doesn't work though. However if I'm trying to set `content: "asd";`, the text appears correctly. Basically I just want to have a house image above that triangle.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div id = "estatecorner" class = "house"></div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#estatecorner {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 80px 80px 0;
  border-color: transparent #67b2e4 transparent transparent;
}

#estatecorner.house::after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(images/mini/house.png);
  content: " ";
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/034pf1zv/)

Comment: 100% with/height of 0 is ... 0 so as your pseudo element has 0 width/height, it's background image isn't displaying

Comment: I set the #estatecorner width and height to 100px. Still doesn't work.

Comment: [really?](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/034pf1zv/1/)

Comment: Well, now it cuts the triangle. Can't I avoid that? Basically I just want to have a house image above that triangle.

Comment: @Radu: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/034pf1zv/3/) what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot! Can you post it as an answer so I can reward you? :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There were two things to take note of here:

1. As web-tiki had mentioned in comments, the `width` and `height` of the pseudo-element were set to `100%` and the parent element had dimensions of 0px x 0px (because the triangle was generated through border hack). Because of this the actual calculated dimensions of the child (pseudo-element) were also 0px x 0px and hence the image was not showing up. The content did show up when you put plain text because text typically overflows.
   The solution to this problem is to **assign an explicit height & width to the child pseudo-element** (as assigning a height & width to the parent would spoil the border hack).
2. When `background-image` is assigned to a pseudo-element and the size of the image is small compared to the container (pseudo-element), the background image is repeated as many times as possible to fit the container element. This should be avoided by setting `background-repeat: no-repeat;` and to position the image within the triangle we have to use the `background-position` property with the appropriate position values in pixels or percentages depending on the needs.

Below is the final snippet (with sample values for height, width & position):

```css
#estatecorner {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 80px 80px 0;
  border-color: transparent #67b2e4 transparent transparent;
}
#estatecorner.house::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/nceI30v.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 75% 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="estatecorner" class="house"></div>
```

---

The below is an alternate approach using a rotated pseudo-element (CSS3 transforms) instead of the border hack to achieve the triangle shape.

```css
#estatecorner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  right: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#estatecorner:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -80px;
  right: -80px;
  height: 138.4px;
  width: 138.4px; /* (80 * 1.732px) */
  background: #67b2e4;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
#estatecorner.house {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/nceI30v.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 75% 35%;
}
```

```html
<div id="estatecorner" class="house"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this;

```
 #estatecorner.house::after {
        content: url('../img/yourimage.jpg');
        position: absolute;
        left:0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Is the code in your fiddle and that in the answer same?

Comment: No I have changed : Please take it from Fiddle :)

Comment: The modified solution is nice and worthy of a vote. Please remove your other answer as it is essentially a duplicate of your own answer.

Comment: Yes, removed the other ans.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the height and width of the psuedo elements in px and not in %  for this case.

```
#estatecorner.house::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 14px;
    height: 13px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/nceI30v.png) no-repeat;
    content: " ";
    left: 50px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

The **reason** is that `#estatecorner` have dimensions of **0 x 0**. So, if you give **100%**
*height* and *width* to its **psuedo** elements then their dimensions will eventually be **0 x 0** too which would be useless.