# Pseudo element background-image does not work

Tags: html, css

As per [other SO solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28646682/9353046), I have tried giving explicit fixed dimensions to the pseudo element (`height: X px; width: X px;`) but even if this worked, I want a scaleable, responsive image which fits its parent element, so hence fixed dimensions are not acceptable to me.  How can I get the `background-image` to show up and be automatically scaleable at the same time?

HTML:

```
<h3>This is a title</h3>
```

CSS:

```
 h3:before{
   background-image:url('https://store.ashenglowgaming.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/cropped-agg-store-logo-4-FULLSIZE-1.jpg'); 
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   display: block;
 }
```

Comment: use `content:""` in  `h3:before`....BTW why not use `background-image` in `h3` itself

Comment: I specifically want the logo to appear above the heading, not inside it.

Comment: `background-position: 0% 0%;` does nothing for me.  No image to be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
h3:before{
    background-image: url(https://store.ashenglowgaming.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/cropped-agg-store-logo-4-FULLSIZE-1.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    content: '';
    height: 110px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I can enforce a minimum width?  `min-width: 150px` does not work?

Comment: @user136649 You can adjust the width by    background-size: auto 60%;

Comment: @user136649 You can give background-size: 100%; and then adjust width and height.

Answer (score 0):

try adding these styles to your pseudo element

```
content: "";
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
```

Comment: I'm scared of using `absolute`.  It usually messes up the flow of my document as other elements will no longer respect its presence, resulting in overlapping elements...

Comment: since we are applying absolute relative to its parent h3, it wont affect any other elements. It can affect only the elements inside the h3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background` in `h3` itself and use `background-size` to adjust the size.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
h3 {
  background-image: url(https://store.ashenglowgaming.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/cropped-agg-store-logo-4-FULLSIZE-1.jpg);
  background-size: auto 40px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: My `h3` title is now being forced out of the flow of the document and elements around it are ignoring it, resulting in overlapping content - is this expected?

Comment: @user136649 no its not expected..looks like you are using `position:absolute`...it will be good if you can share a working example to see the actual issue....

Comment: Actually, I understand what the problem is.  Firstly, the `height` must now take into account the height of the title itself - but the problem is that the height of the text varies, as it will word-wrap.  Hence you can never fully ensure the title will not overlap with the image and be fully accommodated inside the container with this method?  The text size is variable, but we are using a fixed `padding-top` to clear the title.

Comment: @user136649 you want your background-image to be full width or a fixed size...? I applied the `40px` padding-top and 40px height of background-image to prevent the  overlap...

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand what you are trying to do.  But now you also have to extend the `padding-top` height to include the title text of `h3` itself, so it will not overlap with the text _below_ the `h3` title.  But the title text height is not fixed - it word-wraps depending on the screen width.  This is always the problem with using a minimal example for real-world application...

Comment: @user136649 I know the `height` of title is not fixed...I updated my answer using a long title...it will not effect the `background-image` and also not overlap

Comment: You are right my friend - this is a problem of my website - you can see screenshot [here](https://store.ashenglowgaming.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/overlapping.png).  On this occasion it is easier for me to use @athi's and @Anuresh's `:before` approach, as it avoids that problem without me having to edit my website even more.  But I will credit you with an upvote.  I really appreciate the effort you put in.

Answer (score 0):

I have added `content: '';` and specified a `height` and also `min-width` for the pseudo element.

```css
h3:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMdl8cg3CDenBgBdDey8W2KUfDIfKO7ZcPk6c5KtuLn8OJBzu8');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  This is a title
</h3>
```