# Bootstrap Columns Stack past background image creating whitespace

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have created a website that serves up templates with Angular, I have styled the site using CSS and Bootstrap (for easier mobile responsiveness etc).  The site looks good on desktop/mobile but if you resize the window, the columns stack like they are supposed to, but the background image pushes up and leaves white-space underneath, with the columns tiling out past the bottom of the background.  This also happens when the developer tools window is pulled up (mine comes up from the bottom).  It creates white-space.  Is there a way to make the background image never shift?  On mobile I added a media query that puts the stacked columns inside a scroll box with a max-height, I have less whitespace but still a little bit at the bottom.  I tried background position center and background attachment fixed to no avail.  I have included screenshots of what it is doing as well.

This is the base HTML of the app -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Goldbee Dev</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/styles/all.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Roboto|Titillium+Web|Rock+Salt|Condiment|Mate+SC|Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">


    <div ng-view></div>








<script src="vendor/angular.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="dist/scripts/global.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The home template that loads in the beginning -

```
<div class="container" id="main-container">
    <div class="title-area">
        <h1 class="home-title">GoldbeeDev 
            <img class="hvr-buzz" src="images/bee-icon-11.png">
        </h1>
        <h4>
            <button class="link hvr-hang" ng-click="contact()">Contact</button>|
                <button class="link hvr-hang" ng-click="about();">About</button>|
                    <button class="link hvr-hang" ng-click="portfolio()">Portfolio</button>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

When portfolio is clicked it loads this template -

```
 <img class="homelogo hvr-rotate" src="images\home.png" ng-click="$location.path('/')">
 <div class="container">



<div ng-include="portfolioPath" onload="finishLoading()">

</div>
 </div>
```

This is the portfolio home ng-include HTML(where I'm experiencing these problems) -

```
<div class="container pages" id="main-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img class="portfolio-thumb hvr-grow" src="images\quotespic.png" ng-click="portClick(portfolioTemplates[1].url)">
                <p class="project-text">JS Quote Generator</p>
                </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img class="portfolio-thumb hvr-grow" src="images\tictacpic.png" ng-click="tictacStart()">
                <p class="project-text">Tic Tac Toe JS</p>
                </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img class="portfolio-thumb hvr-grow" src="images\moviesearchpic.png" ng-click="movieStart()">
                <p class="project-text">Movie Search</p>
                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img class="portfolio-thumb hvr-grow" src="images\paginationpic.png" ng-click="portClick(portfolioTemplates[2].url)">
                <p class="project-text">jQuery Pagination</p>
                </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img class="portfolio-thumb hvr-grow" src="images\redwolfpic.png" ng-click="portClick(portfolioTemplates[3].url)">
                <p class="project-text">Video Background Homepage</p>
                </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img class="portfolio-thumb hvr-grow" src="images\singlepagepic.png" ng-click="recipeClick()">
                <p class="project-text">Angular Single Page App</p>
                </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS -

```
#main-container {
  margin-top: 5%;
}

#main-container:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('../../images/bluefuzzbg.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -99;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.portfolio-thumb {
  max-width: 325px;
}
```

screens -

[image]

[image]

[image]

This issue seems to happen on other templates outside the portfolio too, just not as bad.  I'm open to any suggestions/tips, and I appreciate you taking the time to read this.

Comment: Remove `no-repeat` from your background and put this to repeat the background `background-repeat: repeat;`. This repeats in both x and y directions.

Comment: @Kavindra I tried that, it still shows whitespace, and I wouldnt want the background to look like tiles as well, i just want it to cover everything.

Comment: Checkout this: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/. I think it is exactly what you need.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but this doesn't help me, as I'm applying a background to pseudo class on an ID on each of the templates..

Comment: try to check that post. i think that will be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/a/28646682/3047033